# How do I prevent the [div] when clicked on from pushing the content below down?

Tags: html

When I click on the [div] on both codes, the bottom part drops down, how do I fix it so it doesn't drop down. How do I have 0 margin between the [div] and the content below after the [div] is clicked?

It's on here: 
http://testblogty678.blogspot.com/

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYwvu.png

```
<a href="" style="display:block; margin: 0px 0px 0 0px;width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#00a0b0; color:#000000; border-top-left-radius:50px; "></a>

<a href="" style="display:block; margin: -50px 0px 0 54px;width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#6a4a3c; color:#000000;"></a>

<a href="" style="display:block; margin: -50px 0px 0 108px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#cc333f;color:#000000; "></a>

<a href="" style="display:block; margin: -50px 0px 0 162px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#eb6841;color:#000000; "></a>

<a href="" style="display:block; margin: -50px 0px 0 216px; width: 50px; height: 50px;background-color:#edc951;color:#000000; border-top-right-radius:50px; "></a>

<div style="width:266px;" onclick="myObject=document.getElementById('myObj5'); 
myObject.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'">

<a style="display:block; width: 88px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer; background-color:#ffffff; color:#000000; 
border-left: 89px solid #00ffff;border-right: 89px solid #ff00ff;border-radius: 50px; "> </a>
</div>

<div id="myObj5" style="display: none;">

</div>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="display:block; margin: 0px 0px 0 0px;width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#00a0b0; color:#000000; " onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#abe9f7'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#00a0b0'"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="display: block; margin: -50px 0px 0 54px; width: 50px; height:50px; background-color:#6a4a3c;color:#000000;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#badac5'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#6a4a3c'"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="display:block; margin: -50px 0px 0 108px; width: 50px; height: 50px;background-color:#cc333f; color:#000000; " onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#b7ab9d'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#cc333f'"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="display:block; margin: -50px 0px 0 162px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#eb6841;color:#000000;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#4679c7'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#eb6841'"></a>

<a href="" target="_blank" style="display:block; margin: -50px 0px 0 216px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color:#edc951; color:#000000;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#45bf21'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#edc951'"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways.

**1st** way: Adding `line-height: 0px;`

The "object element" is an "inline element" and behaves like text. This is why line-height works here.

```
<div id="myObj5" style="display: none;line-height: 0px;">
```

**2nd** way: Adding `style="display:block;"` to object

```
<object data="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="display:block;" id="player1" width="266" height="24">
```

Answer (score -1):

hay did you try using flex box css, it is a a property in which you have to set display:flex; in parent div and all code will be flexible on your command you can see more on w3schools's web page about it.

Comment: I want to know how to do it through inline css/html, cause it's going on a page that only accepts inline css/html, and it's only a single code.

Comment: yah but u can also add it using inline css

Comment: I'm just not going for the flexbox method, but thanks.

Comment: style="display:flex; flex-direction: column;" write this in parent div and all nested divs will be come in a flow.